# Scrapy xpath scraping meta

Tags: xpath, scrapy

I'm scraping with scrapy this url: http://quotes.toscrape.com/

it works great when I do:

```
response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='keywords']/@content").extract()
response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='keywords'][1]/@content").extract_first()
```

but when I try to get the second meta from that list of metas using the index

```
response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='keywords'][2]/@content").extract_first()
```

it doesn't work.

What am I missing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap the expression before index in parenthesis:

Instead of:

```
"//meta[@itemprop='keywords'][2]/@content"
```

It should be:

```
"(//meta[@itemprop='keywords'])[2]/@content"
```

This is needed because you have parameter operators in your xpath.

You can test this:

```
$ scrapy shell "http://quotes.toscrape.com/"
In [1]: response.xpath("//meta[@itemprop='keywords'][2]/@content").extract_first()

In [2]: response.xpath("(//meta[@itemprop='keywords'])[2]/@content").extract_first()
Out[2]: 'abilities,choices'
```

Comment: Thank you! Just one quick question: What editor do you use? Sublimetext?

Comment: I'm not sure how is that relevant but I'm using Vim or Pycharm+ideavim. The code in this example are taken from terminal `scrapy shell` command which launches `ipython` shell if you have ipython installed.

Comment: Thanks. Good to know: vim and pycharm are in my list, I have to try them. Right now, I'm working with sublime text which seems to be great for now (I've heard very good things about it). I have no problem with the scrapy shell (despite I'm a little bit lost with those cpython, ipython things. I'll have to know the python interpreters).

Comment: Ipython, ptpython and bpython are all interpreter shells not interpreters themselves. They basically add functionality to shell like history, autocomplete, highlights etc. `scrapy shell` command supports all of these 3 shells including the default shell python comes with.

Comment: Thanks, good to know! I've investigated python interpreters such as cPython, iPython, jPython, IronPython... It's important to make the difference between interpreters and interpreters shells.